# Android2.3 camera HAL capture picture issue

Tags: camera

I'm working an Android 2.3 project and have some questions with Camera HAL implementation.

It takes me a lot of time to capture pictures, about 4s, how do I reduce it? The camera sensor is  ov3640 on this project. I try to wait for 2 Vsync and capture the 3rd frame follow the Ov3640 spec for capture picture instead of sleep 1s directly when it complete the autofocus.

My second question is, how do I calculate the Vsync time?